# How to add a custom search engine to Firefox?

Tags: firefox, search

Is there a way I can add a custom search URL to the Firefox search bar? e.g. I'd like to provide a URL such as `http://blahblah.com?search=%s`, where Firefox replaces the `%s` with the content of the search box.

Both IE and Opera can do this, but I can't figure out how to set it up in Firefox.

Comment: adding a bookmark pointing to its query (with a shortcut on it) was the easiest (eg: bookmark https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query= )

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9963256/712526

Answer (score 139, accepted):

<sub>*The method to do this has changed - this answer is how to do it in 2018. Read further down to see more recent answers*</sub>

---

Add keywords to the address bar:

For example, you can set up your browser to search for `bread` at stackoverflow.com by simply typing `so bread` into the omnibar.

Do this by right-clicking on the search bar on the website you commonly search. You can do this for the Search field on *any* website.

[image: Right click on the search bar]

Specifically:

1. Go to the site you want to use to search
2. Right-Click on the search box you fill out on their page (not Firefox's)
3. Select "Add a keyword"
4. Enter the keyword to use when you want to search in that site (eg: "so")

Comment: I wish chrome had this.

Comment: @Jed Daniels Chrome does have it in the form of custom search engines - Options -> Manage Search Engines

Comment: @DanH, yes, but the chrome functionality is frustratingly lacking compared to the firefox ability. For example, it only works with search engines that have the search terms in the URL, and you have no control over which searches get added.

Comment: @Jed Daniels You can add searches manually, but I agree, in Chrome they aren't nearly as user friendly or featureful as in Firefox.  Chrome's weak support was one of the reasons I created an alternative to built-in custom search engines - it's at http://shortmarks.com if you want to check it out.

Comment: It is not possible to create search keywords on all websites (at least through the context menu), for instance www.gog.com.

Comment: A downside to this method is that it is not possible to enter an empty keyword, therefore keyword search can't replace a search engine.

Comment: Is there more updated info on this maybe?  Just downloaded latest Firefox on macOS and this doesn't work. :-(

Comment: This is not working now

Comment: This still works, at least on some machines (Firefox 68, Windows 10)

Comment: Working on Firefox 70 on MacOS. Remember to perform the search in the URL bar and *not* the search bar.

Comment: Of course, this only works if there is a search-box available to click on, and worse, it doesn't let you customize the actual query. I can't believe Firefox still doesn't let you natively add customize search engines which Chrome has let you do since it first came out. :-|

Comment: @Synetech I shared a solution to customize "One-Click Search Engines", a search box is not needed and it is possible to customize the query by adding additional HTTP GET parameters if needed: https://superuser.com/questions/7327/how-to-add-a-custom-search-engine-to-firefox/1566328#1566328

Comment: @user598527 The empty `""` keyword *does* use your usual search engine, with or without the quotes. :-)

Comment: @baptx, that's great, but you shouldn't have to do so much manual work. For all of its (_many_) faults, at least Chrome let you easily add any kind of custom search engines with two clicks. :-|

Comment: @baptx: What would be better is for Firefox to fix this - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1683969

Comment: Tried the bookmark method, which bizarrely works from url but not from their search bar. There also doesn't seem to be any way to suppress the escaping of the input string. On archive.org, I very often use `http://web.archive.org/web/*/` with the original url behind it to quickly search archived versions, but this does not work if the colons and slashes of the url behind it get escaped to `%3A` and `%2F`.

Answer (score 204):

> I'd like to provide a URL such as `http://blahblah.com?search=%s` where Firefox replaces the `%s` with the content of the search box.

You can do this with Firefox! Add a bookmark with that URL, where `%s` is the search query, then simply set a keyword for the bookmark. You can then search using `<key> <search term>` in the address bar. For example, the bookmark `http://www.google.com/search?q=%s` with keyword `g` means you can type `g stack overflow` in the address bar to search Google for "stack overflow".

Alternatively, go to the site you want to search, right click in the search box and click "Add a keyword for this search".

Comment: I momentarily thought this doesn't work anymore, but then I noticed I had put the keyword in the "Tags" field.  It's working now!

Comment: And what if I don't want a bookmark? What if I only want a search engine without bookmarking it?

Comment: @Synetech why would you be opposed to bookmarks?

Comment: Best answer IMO, as it depends only on URLs, not website-specific search boxes.

Comment: Apparently putting the %s in the domain part of the URL is now deprecated/broken in FF67 and up. See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1553377

Comment: Although it's very counter-intuitive, it works (v69.0)

Comment: @Synetech Put it anywhere that is not "bookmarks toolbar" or a subfolder of that. I have never seen those bookmarks showing up anywhere except in menu→library→bookmarks→show all bookmarks, which is hidden enough in my opinion. I honestly have no idea what the difference between "bookmarks menu" and "other bookmarks" is.

Comment: @FabianRöling, the bookmark still exists. That might work "well enough", but (1) it's just sweeping it under the rug, and (2) shouldn't be necessary since there is a system that doesn't involve bookmarks. (I usually use the `Add custom search engine` add-on, but do have some bookmarks as well which I keep in a dedicated `Search Engines` folder. :-|)

Comment: @qed: it's not awesome at all. This functionality should be exposed in Preferences -> Search, but it's not - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1683969

Comment: Doesn't work for Internet Archive's Wayback Machine (`wayback <paste url>`) because the `:` is url-encoded. Otherwise, this method works great in my 2-year experience with it.

Comment: For German Users: keyword = Schlüsselwort, not Schlagwort (tag)

Comment: Using Firefox `105.0.1` (64-bit) on Linux Mint 21. I can confirm this works!

Answer (score 106):

Actual answer:

[@Kleinfrund's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1399652/1001697) is valid but Firefox doesn't always recognize sites that support search. If the website doesn't show up using [@Kleinfrund's](https://superuser.com/a/1399652/1001697) method, continue reading.

1. Open a new tab and type `about:config` in the address bar
2. In the search box type: `browser.urlbar.update2.engineAliasRefresh`
3. Click on the little + symbol on the right. This is what it should look like after you pressed it:
   [image: boolean true value after pressing plus sign]
4. Go to firefox Settings → Search. Or enter this in the address bar: `about:preferences#search`
5. In the "Search Shortcuts" section you should notice a new "add" button.
   [image: search add button]
6. Press the add button and fill in the name, search engine url and a keyword(optional).
7. Go to the "Default Search Engine" section and select the engine you just added.
8. Enjoy.

(Please note that the engine url should contain a "%s" in the url. Firefox replaces the %s with your search terms. An example of this is https://www.google.com/search?q=%s)

PS: This does not work for search engines that use POST requests.

Comment: Works perfectly thanks !

Comment: Worked for me. Too bad this is a somewhat secret, backdoor feature.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Did anybody submit a bug to make this config option the default? This isn't a complex feature, so I don't know why they would hide it.

Comment: @SineSwiper I think this is what you're looking for: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1195005

Comment: **This is the actual answer**, everything else is just ugly and super inconvenient workarounds.

Comment: This is exactly the correct answer rather than other (though working) workarounds.

Comment: except `browser.urlbar.update2.engineAliasRefresh` no longer exists, nor does an Add button in that preferences ☹

Comment: @mirabilos Sorry, but that's not correct. I'm currently using 118.0.2(latest version at this time) on windows. The property is still there and it still adds the add button. Are you sure you're using firefox? If you provide some information about which browser you're using exactly and on what OS then maybe we can help you out?

Comment: @BugSquanch yes, I’m using the latest 115.3.1esr

Comment: @mirabilos I just downloaded 115.4.0esr (a slightly newer version but the changelog doesn't indicate any changes to the enginealiasrefresh property) and it still works for me. Are you maybe using a work/school computer that locks some of the firefox settings out? I'm afraid I can't help you in that case.

Comment: @BugSquanch no, stock Debian setting, only `browser.urlbar.update2.emptySearchBehavior` exists under update2

Comment: @mirabilos Hmm, that's weird. Are you sure that you pasted (or typed) the entire string "browser.urlbar.update2.engineAliasRefresh" into the search box? It's not a setting you can just toggle on/off so it won't show up until after you've added it manually. You need to manually add it by hitting the + after typing in the complete string. Please let me know if that was the problem. I'll update my instructions with an extra step to make it more clear that this isn't a default setting if that's the case

Comment: For FF115 this should be marked the correct answer.

Comment: It works, but the icon generated is the generic grey "search" icon.  How do you get it to use the actual favicon of the site in your URL?

Comment: @mirabilos The setting indeed doesn't exist when you just search for it, no. But it gives you the option to _create_ it, and that activates it. Just tested it and it works.

Comment: I wish there was an option to not URL-escape the search string though. My archive.org url search on `http://web.archive.org/web/*/%s` doesn't work...

Comment: Amazing answer. Thank you!

Comment: Note, this does not work with `file:///…` URIs (in Firefox 122 on Debian) ☹️

Answer (score 43):

The actual, no-bookmark solution for this task:

1. Open a web page that has a search on it (e.g. SuperUser: [superuser.com](https://superuser.com)).
2. In the address bar, expand the address bar by clicking on it.
3. If the website supports searching, it will show up in the bottom area of the expanded address bar.  Click the plus icon that is enclosed in a green circle. This adds the web page’s search to the search engines in your preferences.

[image: Screenshot of the bottom of Firefox's expanded address bar when on superuser.com]

Alternatively:

1. Open a web page that has a search on it (e.g. SuperUser: [superuser.com](https://superuser.com)).
2. Right-click on the address bar.
3. If the website supports searching, where will be an option to add it.

[image: Screenshot of the Firefox's context menu for the address bar when on superuser.com]

If you want to set a keyword (e.g. `su`) for this search, follow these steps:

1. Open the search preferences (or type the following URI in your address bar: `about:preferences#search`)
2. In the table under the column for “Keyword”, double-click in order to set your own keyword.

Comment: It's sad that FF allows to do that only for web sites which explicitly provide this feature.

Comment: @Monsignor It's amazing how impossible it is it add a search engine in Firefox, compared to Chrome. I filed a bug against this at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1683969

Comment: Thank you so much for that reminder! I did this in the past, but browsers changed so much and it was said that using addons.mozilla.org would be the easiest way. But I end up with installing extensions, which is so painfully terrible getting served results that you know are bad. I did create xml or rdf or what ever files by hand 15 years ago, things were said to improve with every product generation. It's not the case, it's just driving "customers" to big corporations. :-(

Comment: @LiveWireBT I assume this is how they earn money - by making sure that the search-engines that don't pay to have their name in the list will be locked out for most Firefox users.

Comment: Except, it doesn't work for Searx pages :/

Comment: How do we remove search engines added in this way? When I click on the search engine name that I added in this fashion in settings, the "Remove" button is disabled / grayed out.

Comment: @CollinBarrett That’s strange. The "Remove" button for a search engine added this way is working for me. I’ve just added the search engine for superuser.com and removed it again without issue.

Comment: @kleinfreund ah, weird. maybe it's a bug in the version I'm using. I am on the latest Developer Edition for macOS which isn't guaranteed to be a stable channel.

Comment: In Firefox Android you can add a custom search engine with the %s thing again: https://www.findfind.it/n/de.deu?query=%s

Comment: You add search a custom search engine for any website in Firefox, even if doesn't explicitly support this feature, but it's hidden behind a feature flag. See: https://superuser.com/a/1756774/481524

Comment: This is how I add Wikipedia search shortcuts! I've been using it for years, and it still works now (in Firefox 120.0.1 on Ubuntu). Thanks for reminding me how to do this. It's so upsetting that it's not even mentioned on the search settings page.

Comment: This should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 30):

The [Add custom search engine](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/add-custom-search-engine/) extension lets you create a new search engine and customize it.

Comment: I use this for my custom Google Search Engine.

Comment: Nice. Needed to use this to search using Duckduckgo's POST mode.

Comment: You have to install an add-on to be able to add a custom search engine. It's little things like this that make it so hard to leave Chrome. :-(

Comment: doesn't exist anymore. found another one: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/add-custom-search-engine/

Comment: See this other answer for an extension that is active: https://superuser.com/questions/7327/how-to-add-a-custom-search-engine-to-firefox/1474187#1474187

Comment: An extension should not be needed for such basic functionality. Chrome doesn't need one. If you think Firefox should step up, comment on this bug - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1683969

Comment: No need for any extension, this is supported in Firefox, but hidden behind a feature flag. See: https://superuser.com/a/1756774/481524

Answer (score 21):

Your best bet is to go to [the Mycroft Project](https://mycroftproject.com/) and search for an already made search engine plugin.

If you can't find one you can create your own on [the submissions page](https://mycroftproject.com/submitos.html). Full instructions are available.

Comment: Wow this saved the day for me! This answer should be much higher upvoted. If you want to modify one of your default search engines, you may need to change the plugin name slightly

Comment: I was able to add duckduckgo POST to my firefox using the Mycroft search engine.

Comment: I thought @Pluto was exaggerating ... I simply wanted `hub.docker.com` and it was there.

I would add this answer should be a lot more specific. You click on the search to add and THEN click the URL bar to see the "add to search" at the bottom

Answer (score 9):

[Ready2Search](http://ready.to/search/en/) is also an available free service that helps you do this for any site. It makes search plug-in for Internet Explorer, Firefox, Chrome, and Google Toolbar with great customization options (icons, query parameters, etc.).

[image: Screenshot of Ready2Search]

Answer (score 7):

## Alternative way for custom search

For an example **Google Translate string**: `https://translate.google.com/m/translate#auto/en/%s` so [top answer here](https://superuser.com/a/7336/230571) doesn't work. So I found a workaround with the plugin: [add-custom-search-engine](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/add-custom-search-engine/)

#### And here we go:

[image]

Goes to :

[image]

Comment: This extension works perfectly to add a custom search engine. It should be a core part of Firefox, not an extension!

Comment: Thanks for this. This works great and is one of the more user-friendly solutions. I'd rather not use the bookmarks solution as I mirror my Firefox bookmarks from another browser. This solution ensures that my custom search engines don't get messed up when I do a mirror or syncing of bookmarks.

Comment: @galacticninja plus the "bookmark search engines" are just just straight up castrated. They show way fewer suggestions, and when I do wanna select a suggestion it just searches using the default engine.

Comment: Does this approach URL encode the search term?

Comment: Perfect. If you need two (or more) keywords in separate positions of a URL, make a webpage like `mysite.com/search.php` with the code below, then use `mysite.com/search.php?query=%s` in the plugin.


`<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<?php 


list($first, $second) = explode(' ', $_GET['query']);


$target = "0; url=http://www.website.com?kwd1=" . $first . "&kwd2=" . $second;


echo "$target";


?>"/></head><body></body></html>`


Searching `this that` with the custom search will get you to `http://www.website.com?kwd1=this&kwd2=that`.

Answer (score 6):

**New solution** (since the previous one does not work anymore):

Now if you visit a website like Twitter, Firefox will let you add the Twitter search easily (https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/add-or-remove-search-engine-firefox). But in case you want to add another website that is not supported, you will need a web server like Apache.
Below would be the solution for Twitter in case they don't use the search engine file `opensearch.xml` anymore.

Create a file, for example `twitter_search.htm` (this HTML source code is used on twitter.com, I just removed the `/` before `opensearch.xml`):

```xml
<link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" href="opensearch.xml" title="Twitter">
```

Then create another file, with the same name used in the href parameter of the previous HTML code, for example `opensearch.xml` with this content (this XML source code is used at https://twitter.com/opensearch.xml):

```xml
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" xmlns:moz="http://www.mozilla.org/2006/browser/search/">
  <ShortName>Twitter</ShortName>
  <Description>Twitter Search</Description>
  <Url type="text/html" method="get" template="https://twitter.com/search?q={searchTerms}"/>
  <Image width="16" height="16">https://abs.twimg.com/favicons/favicon.ico</Image>
  <InputEncoding>UTF-8</InputEncoding>
  <moz:SearchForm>https://twitter.com/search-home</moz:SearchForm>
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

If needed, customize these files to replace the search URL, search form URL, name, description and icon. Put these 2 files in a folder of your web server and open the HTML file that you can find by visiting http://localhost in your web browser. You will be able to add your custom search engine to Firefox.

**Previous solution** (not working anymore):

Here is how I restored the Twitter search engine for Firefox, which seems to have been removed in Firefox 78 (you could create a search for other websites also based on this answer):

I tested with the Linux version of Firefox (Ubuntu package) but it should work with any operating system by creating the `distribution` folder / subfolders and search plugin file (https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/Distribution_Files).

In my profile folder `.mozilla/firefox/xxx.default/`, there was a file `search-metadata.json` that contained a link to a non-existing file `/usr/lib/firefox/distribution/searchplugins/locale/en-US/twitter.xml`.

So I created this file with the following content (based on the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Creating_MozSearch_plugins and search plugins already present https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/firefox/filelist):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
  <ShortName>Twitter</ShortName>
  <Description>Twitter Search</Description>
  <InputEncoding>UTF-8</InputEncoding>
  <Image height="16" width="16">data:image/x-icon;base64,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</Image>
  <Url type="text/html" method="get" template="https://twitter.com/search?q={searchTerms}"/>
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

To get the Base64 of the latest Twitter icon that you can see above, I downloaded https://twitter.com/favicon.ico and used the Linux command `base64 favicon.ico`.

The following files were present in my profile folder but were not needed anymore so I removed them to avoid potential conflicts (you can backup files in case you want to reuse them): `search-metadata.json`, `search.json`, `search.json.mozlz4`.

The following answers did not work for me but contained useful information:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963256/adding-a-custom-search-engine-to-firefox/10034461#10034461

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963256/adding-a-custom-search-engine-to-firefox/40651019#40651019

Comment: Speaking of search engines, there are many websites which will let the reader [store the icon as a data url](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=convert+image+to+data+url&ia=web) without knowing about base64.

Comment: @jpaugh indeed there are other ways to convert the image. The Linux base64 command has the advantage to not depend on an online third-party tool. There should be similar offline tools for other operating systems also.

Comment: Quite! JavaScript's [btoa](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa) function might be the most available method. I'm imagining that your instructions are almost capable of being carried out by someone who knows nothing of XML or data urls, which is why I added an alternative.

Comment: I couldn't make this work. [This statement from a Firefox developer](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1649971) says they've removed support for defining search engines with XML. Does this answer still work for any of you?

Comment: @aude I noticed a few months ago that my custom Twitter search engine was gone, even if the file is still present. So it looks like it is not working anymore. I used the official web search instead, for example https://twitter.com/search for Twitter. When I have a moment, I will try to find another way to add a custom search engine to Firefox.

Comment: @aude I updated the answer with a new solution.

Comment: @baptx, nice, it's the same method [Mycroft Project](https://mycroftproject.com/) uses now. I personally ended up using the [WebExtension method](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2019/10/15/search-engine-add-ons-to-be-removed-from-addons-mozilla-org/), it works too.

Answer (score 4):

You can also make **complex searches with multiple parameters**, and here’s how.

For instance, imagine you have a two field search like this fictitious example:

> http:// mymusic.com/search?artist=david+bowie&album=ziggy+stardust

You can make a new `mm` search like:

```
javascript:q="%s";if(q.indexOf(",")>0){q=q.split(",");location.href="http://mymusic.com/search?artist="+q[0]+"&album="+q[1]}
```

(in Firefox it would be a bookmark with keyword `mm`)

Then you can directly search for: `mm david bowie,ziggy startdust` (directly in the address bar)

I choose “,” as the separator, but it’s just an example. It’s perfectible, but you get the idea, and anything is possible.

※ Notice that some browsers (including Opera 12) may not execute your JavaScript in a new tab with no preloaded page.

Answer (score 3):

**Update 2022**: Now you can just right-click the URL on the address bar and click `Add <name of the site>`. It will show up in `about:preferences > Search Shortcuts`, from where you can assign a keyword.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For ESR, you can add (and set default) a new search engine using [policies.json](https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates). E.g. use the following:

```
{
  "policies": {
    "SearchEngines": {
      "Default": "DuckDuckGo",
      "Add": [
        {
          "Name": "DuckDuckGo",
          "URLTemplate": "https://duckduckgo.com/?q={searchTerms}&t=h_&kp=1&ia=web",
          "Method": "GET",
          "IconURL": "https://duckduckgo.com/favicon.ico",
          "Alias": "Ducky",
          "Description": "Duck Duck Goose"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The location of the policies file is described e.g. [in this post](https://antiprn.substack.com/p/firefoxs-policies).

Comment: Does this approach URL encode the search term?

Answer (score 1):

As of FF100, for the website searches that cannot be added with [image: Green plus], a solution is to use the **[mozlz4-edit plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mozlz4-edit/)**.

FF stores all the search engines within a file `search.json.mozlz4` that cannot be edited in a regular text editor.

With that plugin, one can directly (but guided) add search engines.

E.g. Adding "AllMusic" as search engine:
[image]

If you want a icon, you can dowload an icon from the website and add it too.

Rem: you have first to locate that `search.json.mozlz4` file.
On Win10 it is in `%appdata%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\xx_profile_id_xx.default-release\`

Comment: Does this approach URL encode the search term?

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as right clicking in a search field.

The other advantage is that this process creates a bookmark for you.  If you use something like [XMarks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xmarks) to synchronize your bookmarks, you can access the same search functionality across all synchronised computers.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to play nicely with the builtin Firefox Sync.

Comment: This is what the accepted answer says. I realize it's 11 years later, but now, this answer has become redundant.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but for those finding this thread now you can click the search icon in the search bar when on the site you want if it has a green + icon on it.

Comment: What if it does not show the green + like on a site (e.g., eBay)?

Answer (score 0):

To mimic chrome's "site search" feature:  https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/ob8ffw/question_custom_url_for_duckduckgo_search_when/h3mcfh7/

worked exactly as expected and super easy to config

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

[As of August 2022]

If you happen to have Duck Duck Go set as your search engine, [!Bangs](https://duckduckgo.com/bang) are another option.

Answer (score 0):

I've created an online web app that lets you add custom search engines to Firefox, simply enter the info then click add and corner click in the URL bar:

https://svelte.dev/repl/8b4c3b768f4041888bd64cbaffbb8135?version=4.1.1

Svelte Code

```
<script>
    let searchUrl = '';
    let name = "";
    let image = "";
    let encoding = "UTF-8";
    let description = "";
    $: error = searchUrl ? (!searchUrl.startsWith('https://') ? 'URL invalid' : '') : 'Search URL must be present';
    function getXML({
  name,
  url,
  image,
  suggestUrl,
  encoding,
  description,
  usePost,
  postParams,
}) {
  const XML_TEMPLATE = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
<ShortName>####REPLACE####</ShortName>
<Description></Description>
<InputEncoding>UTF-8</InputEncoding>
<Image height="16" width="16"></Image>
<Url type="text/html" method="get" template=""></Url>
<Url type="application/x-suggestions+json" method="get" template=""></Url>
</OpenSearchDescription>`;
  const parser = new DOMParser();
  const doc = parser.parseFromString(XML_TEMPLATE, "application/xml");

  // Name
  const shortName = doc.getElementsByTagName("ShortName")[0];
  shortName.textContent = name;

  // Search URL
  const searchUrl = doc.querySelector('Url[type="text/html"]');
  searchUrl.setAttribute("template", url.replace(/\%s/g, '{searchTerms}'));
  if (usePost) {
    searchUrl.setAttribute("method", "POST");
    for (const [name, value] of Object.entries(postParams)) {
      const param = doc.createElementNS(
        "http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/",
        "Param",
      );
      param.setAttribute("name", name);
      param.setAttribute("value", value);
      searchUrl.append(param);
    }
  } else {
    searchUrl.setAttribute("method", "GET");
  }

  // Icon
  const img = doc.getElementsByTagName("Image")[0];
  if (image) {
    img.textContent = image;
  } else {
    img.remove();
  }

  // Suggest URL
  const suggestSearchUrl = doc.querySelector(
    'Url[type="application/x-suggestions+json"]',
  );
  if (suggestUrl) {
    suggestSearchUrl.setAttribute("template", suggestUrl);
  } else {
    suggestSearchUrl.remove();
  }

  // Input Encoding
  const inputEncoding = doc.getElementsByTagName("InputEncoding")[0];
  if (encoding) {
    inputEncoding.textContent = encoding;
  }

  // Description
  const desc = doc.getElementsByTagName("Description")[0];
  if (description) {
    desc.textContent = description;
  } else {
    desc.remove();
  }

  const serializer = new XMLSerializer();
  return serializer.serializeToString(doc);
}

    async function addSearchEngine(xml){
        if (document.querySelector("button")?.disabled){return}
        let url = await fetch("https://cors.explosion.workers.dev?https://paste.mozilla.org/api/", {
            "credentials": "omit",
            "headers": {
                "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0",
                "Accept": "*/*",
                "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
                "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
                "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
                "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin"
            },
            "body": `content=${encodeURIComponent(xml)}&format=url&lexer=xml`,
            "method": "POST",
            "mode": "cors"
        }).then(r => r.text()).then(t => t.trim());
        console.log(url)
        window.open(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([
            `
         <head><link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title=${JSON.stringify(name)} href="${url}/raw"></head>
         <h1>Corner click the URL bar and click "Add ${name.replace(/[^a-z0-9 ]+/gi, ' ')}"</h1>
        <style>body {display: grid; place-items: center; height: 100vh;} h1 {font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 2rem; font-weight: 100; width: 100%; display: block; text-align: center}</style>
        `
        ], {type: 'text/html'})), '_blank')
    }
</script>
<div class='container'>
    <h1>Add search engine</h1>
    <input bind:value={name} placeholder="Name"/>
    <input bind:value={searchUrl} placeholder="Search engine URL (use %s for search term)"/>
    <input bind:value={description} placeholder="Description"/>
    <input bind:value={image} placeholder="Image URL (data urls work)"/>
    <input bind:value={encoding} placeholder="Encoding"/>
    {#if error}<span>{error}</span>{/if}
    <button disabled={!!error} on:click={() => addSearchEngine(getXML({name, url: searchUrl, image, encoding: encoding || "UTF-8", description}))}>Add</button>
</div>

<style>
    span {
        font-style: italic;
        font-weight: 200;
        color: #777;
    }
    .container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        gap: 10px;
        width: 80vw;
        max-width: 600px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    input {
        padding: 8px 15px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        border: 1px solid #eee;
    }
    button {
        padding: 8px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    h1 {
        font-weight: 100;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
    }
    
</style>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1207031)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the browser console (`hamburger menu/more tools/browser console`, or `ctrl+shift+j`).

```
Services.search.addUserEngine(
    "Google Verbatim",
    "https://www.google.com/search?q={searchTerms}&tbs=li:1",
    "gv"
);
```

To remove,

```
Services.search.getEngineByAlias("gv").then(engine => Services.search.removeEngine(engine));
```

This service is [documented here](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/toolkit/search/SearchService.html) (appears to be slightly out of date, eg removeEngine isn't listed; you might look in the [implementation source file](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/toolkit/components/search/SearchService.sys.mjs) for more complete info.)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

I believe he's referring to keyword.URL in Firefox's about:config page.

In Firefox's address bar type `about:config`, then search for `keyword.URL` and replace its contents with "https://blahblah.com/search?q=", for example.