# Format Google search box on toolbar to search under google.com.au

Tags: firefox, google-search

I used to be able to search google.com.au using the quick search box on the toolbar. Ever since i updated firefox though, this goes straight to google.com - is there anyway i can revert it to google.com.au?

Answer (score 1):

This add-on might help: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/add-to-search-bar.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you can add a custom search to firefox:

[How to add a custom search engine to Firefox?](https://superuser.com/questions/7327/how-to-add-a-custom-search-engine-to-firefox)