# Firefox adding my own URL as my search engine?

Tags: firefox, url, search-engines

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add a custom search engine to Firefox?](https://superuser.com/questions/7327/how-to-add-a-custom-search-engine-to-firefox)

How can I add my own URL (with a `%s` as the search item) as one of the search engines in Firefox? Right now, it only allows me to add some pre-defined search engines.