# How do I edit the name of a custom search engine in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser, search

I've added a [custom search engine in Firefox](https://superuser.com/q/7327/10259), but then realized that its name/title was too long.

[image]

**How do I edit a custom search engine's name in Firefox?**

I tried going to 'Manage Search Engines...', but it only allows me to edit the keyword, not the name.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can find the Search Providers in your Firefox Profile (search.json)

**C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\profile\search.json**

Replace *user* and *profile* with your profile names.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with the [Organize Search Engines](https://code.google.com/p/organize-search-engines/downloads/list) extension.

It will replace the "manage search engines" dialog with another one which has way more options to, well, manage your search engines :)

Due to a change in the [new search bar in Firefox 34](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/search-bar-add-change-manage-search-engines-firefox), the current latest version of Organize Search Engines (1.7) will only work in Firefox 34 and later versions if `browser.search.showOneOffButtons` in `about:config` is set to 'false' (reverting the search bar to its pre-v34 functionality).

Comment: The author has currently taken down the extension in Mozilla Add-ons, probably because it won't work with the new search bar in Firefox 34, unless you revert it to its old search bar functionality by setting `browser.search.showOneOffButtons` in `about:config` to 'false'. I've suggested an edit adding this info and edited the link to point instead to its Google Code page where it can still be downloaded.