# How do I make Firefox's Google search use a region-specific URL directly?

Tags: firefox, google-search

When I search for something using the Google search engine on Firefox's top right, it first checks www.google.com which then gets redirected to www.google.co.in. When I'm on a slow connection, this unnecessary redirect adds a few agonizing seconds to every search I perform.

How can I change it so that Firefox uses a google.co.in URL by default? I get a `Add <SiteName>` option when I'm on other sites (e.g. right now I have `Add SuperUser`) in the list of search engines, but visiting google.co.in doesn't give me such an option. Is this a hard-coded exception in Firefox? How can I circumvent this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a custom search engine to Firefox?](http://superuser.com/questions/7327/how-to-add-a-custom-search-engine-to-firefox)

Comment: Especially note the answers that point to resources such as [this one](http://mycroftproject.com/submitos.html), which let you search from an existing list or create your own search plugin given a URL. In fact, it looks like a [Google India one already exists](http://mycroftproject.com/search-engines.html?name=google+india), though that one doesn't have a suggestions URL set.

Comment: @Bob Thanks. I knew the keyword search method mentioned in the top answer there, but that's relatively cumbersome, I'll check the other options given.

Comment: @Bob The linked engine searches only among "pages from India" which I don't want, but the "Google IN-en - the web" one on http://mycroftproject.com/search-engines.html?name=google.co.in works very well. And suggestions too work on this one (http://mycroftproject.com/installos.php/13836/google_indian_en.xml) Thank you very much for pointing me to that site.