# How can I customize Firefox's search engines?

Tags: firefox, search, search-engines

Recently I decided to use [duckduckgo](https://duckduckgo.com/) instead of google, and I installed it as a search engine.

The problem is that Firefox uses https://duckduckgo.com/opensearch.xml to know the search url. But I want to customize it using [parameters](https://duckduckgo.com/params).

Then, I tried going to Firefox's profile folder and modifying `search.json` and `searchplugins/duckduckgo.xml` with my own parameters.

It worked at first, but I have Firefox Nightly (updated each day), and after each update I lose my list of search engines.

To recover it, I do:

1. Delete `search.json` and `searchplugins/duckduckgo.xml`
2. Restart firefox
3. Add duckduckgo again
4. Modify `search.json` and `searchplugins/duckduckgo.xml` again

But I don't want to do that everyday. Which is the correct way of customizing search engines?

---

**Note 1**: The difference between an old `search.json` and a new one is minimal:

1.

- `{"version":7,"buildID":"2013110`**9**`03020`**6**`","locale":"en-US","directories":{"Path\\To\\Nightly\\browser\\searchplugins":{"lastModifiedTime":1384`**018305984**`,"engines":`
- `{"version":7,"buildID":"201311`**1**`003020`**5**`","locale":"en-US","directories":{"Path\\To\\Nightly\\browser\\searchplugins":{"lastModifiedTime":1384`**100021250**`,"engines":`

2.

- `"Path\\To\\Profile\\searchplugins":{"lastModifiedTime":1384`**040082109**`,"engines":[{"_id":"[profile]/duckduckgo.xml"`
- `"Path\\To\\Profile\\searchplugins":{"lastModifiedTime":1384`**100281656**`,"engines":[{"_id":"[profile]/duckduckgo.xml"`

3.

- `"_urls":[{"template":"https://duckduckgo.com/?q={searchTerms}`**&myCustomParameter=myCustomValue**`"`
- `"_urls":[{"template":"https://duckduckgo.com/?q={searchTerms}"`

**Note 2**:

I know I can use URL keywords and modify `keyword.URL`, but I want to be able to search with my customized search engine using the search bar too.

Then, my question is not a duplicate of [How to add a custom search engine to Firefox?](https://superuser.com/questions/7327/how-to-add-a-custom-search-engine-to-firefox).

---

**Solution**

It seems the problem was that adding DuckDuckGo using Firefox.

Firefox created the following `DuckDuckGo.xml`:

```
<SearchPlugin xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/2006/browser/search/" xmlns:os="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
<os:ShortName>DuckDuckGo</os:ShortName>
<os:Description>Search DuckDuckGo (SSL)</os:Description>
<os:InputEncoding>UTF-8</os:InputEncoding>
<os:Image width="16" height="16">data:image/x-icon;base64,...</os:Image>
<os:Url type="text/html" method="GET" template="https://duckduckgo.com/?q={searchTerms}">
</os:Url>
</SearchPlugin>
```

But it should be

```
<SearchPlugin xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/2006/browser/search/">
    <ShortName>DuckDuckGo</ShortName>
    <Description>DuckDuckGo. More Privacy. Less Spam.</Description>
    <InputEncoding>UTF-8</InputEncoding>
    <Image height="16" width="16" type="image/x-icon">data:image/x-icon;base64,...</Image>
    <Url type="text/html" method="GET" template="https://duckduckgo.com/">
        <Param name="q" value="{searchTerms}"/>
    </Url>
    <SearchForm>https://duckduckgo.com/</SearchForm>
</SearchPlugin>
```

Not sure if I changed things in `search.json` too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is off-topic, but thanks for the anonymous search engine **DuckDuckGo**.

You can  use this opensearch **Mycroft Project**.

It has everything already created just enter the values into textbox and and you have the XML code.

You can also submit your website search engine [here](http://mycroftproject.com/submitos.html).

### OR

Here are the steps:

1. Need to create an XML file which will contain information about search engine like ShortName, Description, URL etc. Example of XML file [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Creating_MozSearch_plugins)
2. Give a name to that XML file and put it here:

> %APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\XXXXXXXX.default\searchplugins

or here:

> %PROGRAM_FILES%\Mozilla Firefox\searchplugins

3. Modifying FireFox preferences file:

> %APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\XXXXXXXX.default\prefs.js

Simply add/modify this line:

> user_pref("browser.search.selectedEngine", "engine_name");

No needing to modify SQLite database file manually. New search engine will be added automatically after restarting FireFox.

[Source](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-a-Custom-Search-Engine-to-Firefox%27s-Search-Bar-%28Windows-Version%29)

Comment: Using the xml example from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Creating_MozSearch_plugins) fixed the problem. It seems Firefox doesn't know how to create search plugins for itself...

Comment: Seems for now v86.0 x64 only support mycroft project. It's sad.