# Firefox keyword search without URL escaping

Tags: firefox, awesomebar

According to the [documentation of keyword searches](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Using_keyword_searches), you can specify `%S` instead of `%s` in a bookmark to prevent escaping. However, this is not working for me: trying to make a quick search for Wayback Machine always results in escaped URLs being passed, which give an error from the Internet Archive.

Do I understand the documentation correctly? Does this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's currently working in Firefox 70.

```
archgood  https://web.archive.org/web/*/%S
archbad  https://web.archive.org/web/*/%s
archgood https://www.google.com/  https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://www.google.com/
archbad https://www.google.com/  https://web.archive.org/web/*/https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F
```

You probably have the wrong URL if you created the search by right clicking the search box and selecting "Add a Keyword for this Search". Firefox records the form's submission URL, but the Wayback Machine intercepts/cancels form submission and redirects to another location with JavaScript instead.

Note that the capital `%S` only works when you add the search engine via the bookmark editor like this:

[image]

Adding it [on the settings page](https://superuser.com/a/1756774/141595) only allows you specify a lowercase `%s`.

Comment: Using a capital `%S` no longer works, it is not replaced by the query. Would you know o a new method?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke Nope, but it's still working for me in 115.0.3. What version are you on?

Comment: I'm also on 115.0.3 on Mac OS, but when I add a capital `%S`  as a placeholder for the wayback machine, I get a 400 Bad Request when I use it. [These are my settings in Firefox](https://i.imgur.com/Pb6Lzx3.png) and [this is what I get](https://i.imgur.com/X3UNrLY.png) when I try to use it.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke This only works with bookmark keywords. You need to create a bookmark [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwQqx.png). The newer search engines feature doesn't have a way to prevent the query from being escaped. The bookmark keyword feature will probably be removed eventually in favor of search engines.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I thought these were different interfaces to reach the same thing, but apparently not.