# How-To add Brave Search to Firefox Search Bar

Tags: firefox, privacy, brave

I am not yet using Brave browser, because Chrome based. How-To add [Brave Search](https://search.brave.com/) to Firefox Search Bar?

> Brave, the browser which has gained momentum and popularity in recent
> years, is taking another leap forward in its quest to offer users a
> more private and secure internet experience. Starting today, Brave
> browser users will have access to Brave Search in beta, a completely
> new search engine that offers "unmatched privacy."

Source: [MacRumors](https://www.macrumors.com/2021/06/22/brave-search-beta-now-available/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I know link only comment is bad but the primary answer is available here:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/add-or-remove-search-engine-firefox

1. Visit a website that offers an [OpenSearch](https://www.opensearch.org/) search engine ([Brave Search](https://search.brave.com/) supports it).
2. Right Click on the search bar
3. Select `Add "Brave Search"`

[image]

Comment: After trying to unsuccessfully to make Brave my default, I successfully followed these instructions and then, to make Brave search my default, went back to the Search tab in Settings, where Brave had been added as one of the available options.

Answer (score 4):

Settings -> Search Engine -> Add New

Enter name:
Brave Search

Enter URL:
Search.Brave.com/search?q=%s

Comment: This way used to work, but has been removed in new versions of Firefox

Comment: @EinoGourdin, I think you can add it back by setting `browser.urlbar.update2.engineAliasRefresh` to `true` as explained here: https://superuser.com/a/1756774