# Firefox - Replace text in search bar with shortcut

Tags: macos, firefox

Is it possible to somehow replace text in Firefox search bar with shortcut?

E.g. instead of having to type `https://superuser.com/questions` I'd rather type only e.g. 'sq'.

Running on macOS.

Comment: Based on Safari [I don't use FF] Save it as a Bookmark, titled 'sq'. that should drop it into 'bookmarks & history' though you'll still have to click it. [Though mine is so used to me going to Superuser that just 'su' will suggest it as the first option, right in the multibar.]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a custom search engine to Firefox?](https://superuser.com/questions/7327/how-to-add-a-custom-search-engine-to-firefox)